# How to implement adding custom js code snippet feature in React SPA?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a white label web application. I need to implement adding custom js code snippet feature ("tags" in marketing terms) to let marketers add tracking code like google analytics code and heap code.  In the admin app, admins can add custom js code snippet like this.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-160375581-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-160375581-1');
</script>
```

As you can see, I need to support both `<script src/>` and `<script>code</script>`.

In the web app (Create-React-App SPA), I need to add this code snippet in the document. I have no idea how to implement this feature.
I tried to inject this code snippet using React dangersoulySetInnerHTML feature. But innerHTML doesn't allow `<script>`.

Please look carefully at the code snippet sample, it also has to support external script specified with `src` attribute.

This screenshot will help you understand what feature I want to implement.

[image: screenshot of instapage builder]

Comment: Have you considered embedding the script code in the server side?

Comment: I built the user web app using create-react-app. so I only have to render this app on the client-side. And I have to get custom snippets using RestAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the adding custom script feature like this. Please review the code. I hope you suggest another good solution.
The reason I make the cloneScript function is to make HTML script tag that doesn't have "already started" status.
If you don't make sense, please check this doc.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model

```js
const cloneScript = (script) => {
  const s = document.createElement('script');

  // copy attributes
  const attrs = script.attributes;
  for (let i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
    s.setAttribute(attrs[i].name, attrs[i].value);
  }

  // copy inner text of script
  s.text = script.text;

  return s;
};

const addCustomScripts = (custom_tag) => {
  try {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(custom_tag, 'text/html');
    const collection = doc.head.children;
    Array.from(collection)
      .map((script) => cloneScript(script))
      .forEach((script) => document.body.appendChild(script));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};

const str = `
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-160375581-1"></script>
<script id="stella" data-state="inactive">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-160375581-1');
</script>`

addCustomScripts(str);
```

Comment: Hi @Lenin Raj Rajasekaran, Please check my answer. And give me some help.

Comment: Need to add some comments about why you need to clone the scripts after parsing.  also, your example scripts have id ans data-state, but why?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of tracking you're gonna use.

1. you can directly edit the html in public/index.html folder
2. Google Tag Manager has a [react package](https://github.com/alinemorelli/react-gtm) you can use
3. Or you could transform the script into js yourself

   for example

   ```
   const hm = document.createElement("script");
   hm.src = "https://example.com/example.js";
   const s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);
   ```

   look into the source code of [react-gtm](https://github.com/alinemorelli/react-gtm) for a more detailed and polished approach.
4. Or you could use [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) if you don't want to deal with all this, just copy paste and be done with it.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot render them on the server side, you can do them on the client side but it could be **dangerous** if the script has malicious content:

Here is a code sample of how you can do it: https://codesandbox.io/s/2rwqy2m0r

```
import React, { Component, useState, isValidElement }  from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const HtmlComponent = ({ html }) => (
  isValidElement(html) ? html : <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
)

class ScriptComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    eval(this.props.children);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

const htmlTexts = {
  'With h1': {
    description: 'Normal visual HTML elements are rendered corretly',
    html: '<h1>Test</h1>',
  },
  'With script': {
    description: '<script /> tags in HTML are never executed on client side',
    html: '<script>alert(\'test\');</script>',
  },
  'With style': {
    description: '<style /> gets interputed by DOM, and updates element styles',
    html: '<style>body {background: red;}</style>',
  },
  'With script image': {
    description: 'element event actions are triggered so XSS is still possible, even without <scripts /> being evaluated',
    html: '<img src="foo" onerror="(() => alert(\'foo\'))()" />',
  },
  'With button': {
    description: 'element event actions are triggered so XSS is still possible, even without <scripts /> being evaluated',
    html: '<button onclick="(() => alert(\'foo\'))()">Click me</button>',
  },
  'As script element': {
    description: 'Event reacts own script tag doesn\'t evaluate its content',
    html: <script>alert('foo')</script>,
  },
  'As script component': {
    description: 'To run scripts on tag load, a component has to activly execute it',
    html: <ScriptComponent>alert('foo')</ScriptComponent>,
  }
}

function App() {
  const [{ html, description }, setHtml] = useState({});
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>dangerouslySetInnerHTML with script</h1>
      {Object.keys(htmlTexts).map((name, i) => (
        <button
          style={{
            outline: 'none',
            border: 'solid 1px #ddd',
            margin: '10px 10px 30px 0',
            borderRadius: '8px',
            padding: '10px',
            boxShadow: html === htmlTexts[name].html ? '0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3)' : 'none'
          }}
          onClick={() => setHtml(htmlTexts[name])}
        >
          {name}
        </button>
      ))}
      <div>
        {description}
      </div>
      <pre
        style={{
          background: '#222',
          color: '#fff',
          padding: '10px',
        }}
      >
        {isValidElement(html) ? (
          'React Component\n\n' +
          `type: ${typeof html.type === 'string' ? html.type : html.type.name}\n\n` +
          `props: ${JSON.stringify(html.props, null, '  ')}`
        ) : (
          `html:\n\n${html}`
        )}
      </pre>
      <HtmlComponent html={html} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But I think it doesn't support external script. I think only support inline script.

Comment: Replace the prop value with a value from your server

Comment: Sorry, could you explain more detail? It doesn't make sense.